# ReactNative: Does `Linking.addEventListener` fire when the app is running background?(Deep linking)

Tags: react-native

When I set up like this
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking#basic-usage

and open the app via Custom URL Scheme,
`_handleOpenURL` catches the URL if the app is shutdown, but doesn't if the app is running background.(iOS)

So can't I use the `Linking.addEventListener` when the app is already running?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue working on a detached Expo project because I had added the suggested code from https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html to the `*AppDelegate.m` but Expo already provides slightly different functions for handling URL events. Removing the code from the React Native docs made it work for me.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, it turned out to be something wrong in my `AppDelegate.m`.